# Is it necessary to release an event created by clCreateUserEvent() ?

Tags: opencl

I can't find a release method in the docs. Is it hiding somewhere where I can't see?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decrement the reference count of an event using [`clReleaseEvent`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clReleaseEvent.html):

> Decrements the event reference count. The event object is deleted once the reference count becomes zero, the specific command identified by this event has completed (or terminated) and there are no commands in the command-queues of a context that require a wait for this event to complete.

Note however that:

> Developers should be careful when releasing their last reference count on events created by `clCreateUserEvent` that have not yet been set to status of `CL_COMPLETE` or an error. [...]

User events are created with an initial reference count of 1, as per the OpenCL specification (§5.9 Event Objects):

> The OpenCL commands that return an event perform an implicit retain.

Therefore if you haven't performed any additional retain on your user event, passing it to `clReleaseEvent` should delete it immediately. You must take care that your event was marked as complete, otherwise your application may end up in a deadlock.